# Change map icon marker color onclick via Google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, marker

I have a single marker with popup and an "onclick" function that changes the color.

Is it possible to change the color when I close the popup/click for the second time on the marker and return to the initial color of the marker?

Is there a clickoff function?

```
var testmarker = L.marker([53.9, 14.24], {
      icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': '#9c89cc'
      })
    })
    .bindPopup(test1)
    .addTo(map);
testmarker.on('click', function() {
    this.setIcon(
        L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-color': '#FF99FF'
        })
    );      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
   // do stuff
});
```

and check whether the infowindow is open or not. If it is not open, you open it and change the colour of the marker and if it is open, you close it and change the colour of the marker to the initial colour.

Comment: I saw this example...but how It can be used in mapbox?

Comment: I thought you were only using google maps. Is mapbox some sort of plugin? Maybe it's worth adding this in the tags or the question.